# The same URL of a Java script is different from different pages

Tags: asp.net, url, three.js

I am trying to load a resource in with THREE.Js

```
function loadScene(scene) {
            var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
            loader.load("..//scenes//IR.json",
                function (obj) {
                    scene.add(obj);
                },
                function (x) {
                    console.log(x.loaded / x.total * 100 + '%')
                },
                function (err) {
                    console.log('Error: died.')
                }
            );
            return scene;
        }
```

I am using the same script on two different views.
In one view everything is ok and in the other view I get a different URL.

Working Request URL:
https://localhost:44351//scenes//IR.json

Second Request URL:
https://localhost:44351/Funtiongroup//scenes//IR.json

The same script is called every time in a view.

"Funtiongroup" is the controller from this view.

Answer (score 0):

You've specified a relative path to your script file. That path is resolved relative to the URL of the current page.

If you have loaded `https://localhost:44351/Home/`, then your relative path resolves to `https://localhost:44351//scenes//IR.json`.

If you have loaded `https://localhost:44351/Functiongroup/Index/`, then your relative path resolves to `https://localhost:44351/Functiongroup//scenes//IR.json`.

To resolve from the root of the site, drop the `..` at the start of the path:

```
loader.load("/scenes/IR.json",
```

**NB:** You don't need double forward-slashes in the path, unless you're using a very unusual web server.